# Alternate row colors when you have rowspan

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<table class="altRowTable">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.altRow tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DEDFDE");
  });
</script>
```

This works fine until I have some rows that contains a `rowspan` (it's not consistent across the rows).

So I have something like this (below "-" represents a space - can't really do tables in SOF :) )

```
|---ID---|---name---|---Number---|   
|---1----|---joe----|-----1------|   
|--------|---tom----|-----2------|   
|---2----|---joe----|-----3------|   
|---3----|---joe----|-----4------|   
|---4----|---joe----|-----6------|   
|---5----|---joe----|-----5------|   
|--------|---tom----|-----3------|
```

How can i keep all the rows within the rowspan the same backcolor ?

Comment: As you build the table can you just alternate the classname?

Comment: Tricky problem. James's suggestion of manually using classnames might be the easiest way to go.

Comment: hehe I did not get the problem. is it good for me? ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There may be a slicker way to do it, but here's one way:

```
$("table.altRow tr").filter(function() { 
  return $(this).children().length == 3;
}).filter(':even').addClass('alt'​​​​​​);

$("tr.alt td[rowspan]").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, this.rowSpan - 1).addClass('alt');
});
```

This uses a CSS class instead of the color, like this:

```
.alt { background-color​: #DEDFDE; }​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JtPw5/), you can swap `:even` and `:odd` in the first code block to do whichever pattern you want (with the example, `:odd` doesn't illustrate it well, since that's the rows *without* `rowspan` cells).

What this does is find the rows with *all* the cells, not partial rows, gets the odd or even ones of those and applies a class.  Then the second pass looks at *those* rows, and if they have any `rowspan=""` cells it gets that `.rowSpan` (DOM property), minus one for the current row, and applies the class that many rows down, via [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Comment: Really coooool Ex. @Nick i like it +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @nick-craver doesn't work for tables with cells which use both the rowspan **and** colspan attributes. The modified code below accounts for this, though it does assume that the total number of  tags and their colspan values are equal for all rows.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though @nick-craver!

```js
// This the maximum number of columns in your table, E.g. In this case a column crossing the whole table would have colspan="3"

var column_count = 3;

$("table.altRow tr").filter(function() {

  // Adds row children and colspan values of those children

  var child_count = 0;
  $("td", this).each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr('colspan') != null) {
      child_count += parseInt($(this).attr('colspan'));
    } else {
      child_count += 1;
    }
  });

  return child_count == column_count;
}).filter(':even').addClass('alt');

$("tr.alt td[rowspan]").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, this.rowSpan - 1).addClass('alt');
});
```