# Set alternating row class with rowspans and jquery

Tags: jquery

If I have a html table with `<tr>`'s, but with those tr's there are `<td>`'s with rowspans, I need to figure out the quickest way to set the alternating row class for coloring with jQuery. Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternate row colors when you have rowspan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432683/alternate-row-colors-when-you-have-rowspan)

Comment: thanks @Reigel however this assumes that there are 3 td's, whereas in my table, it can be a variation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is ripped from [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432683/alternate-row-colors-when-you-have-rowspan/3432753#3432753),

```
$("table.altRow").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var numTD = $this.find("tr:has(td[rowspan]):first td").length;
    $this.data('numTD', numTD).find("tr").filter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        return $this.children().length == $this.closest('table').data('numTD');
    }).filter(':even').addClass('alt');

})

$("tr.alt td[rowspan]").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, this.rowSpan - 1).addClass('alt');
});​
```

then css

```
.alt { background-color​: #DEDFDE; }​
```

[have fun playing with the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JtPw5/5/)

Comment: Nice generalised solution, still works well nearly four years later :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this. The row span is going to take from the first row it's from.

```
$('table tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('table tr:even').addClass('even');
```

Then in your css

```
table tr.odd td {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: this has some problems with rowspan... that is why the title says *Set alternating row class with rowspans*... ;)

Comment: Can you post an actual example of the problem then?