# Coloring every second row with rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I want to color every second row of a table. While every regular table can be colored using this:

```
$('tr:odd').css( "background-color", "orange" );
```

In my case there are several `rowspan`, what makes the task more difficult.

This is my desired output:

[image: desired table]

Using this code above doesn't lead to the desired result:

[image]

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4j54g8Lq/).

```js
$('tr:odd').css("background-color", "orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is answered extensively here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200997/how-to-use-nth-child-for-styling-with-a-table-with-rowspan

Comment: try `tr:nth-child(odd) {background: red;}`

Comment: @herrh what difference do you think that will make???

Comment: @Kit: The solution there excludes rowspans, what doesn't apply in my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432683/alternate-row-colors-when-you-have-rowspan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate row colors when you have rowspan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432683/alternate-row-colors-when-you-have-rowspan)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this:

```js
$("table tr").filter(function() { 
  return $(this).children().length == 3;
}).filter(':odd').addClass('alt');

$("tr.alt td[rowspan]").each(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, this.rowSpan - 1).addClass('alt');
});
```

```css
.alt { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no need to iterate all the rowspan td's in same row